# Pair correlation - basics

Tags: functions

I'm not sure whether this is the right forum for this question, but I was wondering how the pair correlation function works in very basic terms (just for one dimension for now). Say I had a list of data such as

$$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$$

how would the function work at this very basic level?